# Calling interrupts using a register

Tags: c++, assembly, osdev

I am trying to call some interrupts from protected mode in C++ by going back to real mode, calling the interrupt and returning back to protected mode. I get an error:

> C2400 : Improper operand type

I'm trying to fix this, but I don't know where to start. Here is an extract from my code:

```
void intupt(char intr) //Call interrupt function. INTR is number of interrupt.
{
    pm2rm(); //Protected Mode To Real Mode
    __asm
    {
        mov al, [intr] //Put intr to AL register
        int al // call interrupt using AL
    }
    rm2pm(); //Real Mode to Protected Mode
}
```

Why am I getting that error? Any suggestions on why that's happening?

Comment: To call real mode interrupt just push the flags and do a far call via the interrupt vector table.

Comment: What compiler are you using? What does the code in `pm2rm()` do? Does it reload the CS register with an appropriate real mode segment value? Or does it only clear the PE bit in CR0?

Answer (score 4):

`int` never takes a register as an operand, only a byte literal. If you want to be able to specify the interrupt to call in a register then you will need to use a dispatch table.

Comment: what is dispatch table?

Comment: @ASD sounds like a really good question, and might be a bit big to cover properly in comments. If you can't find a good answer with a websearch, I recommend making a new question. Odds are good someone here can give a good answer that is relevant to your program.

Comment: @ASD: Like a C `switch` statement, with a `case` for `int 0x1`, another for `int 0x2`, etc.  [Google would tell you this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dispatch_table), if you even bothered to ask a computer first.

Comment: Dispatch table already exists in this case as the interrupt vector table itself. I'd be inclined to  pushf, and do a far _CALL_ via a register that contains the address of the interrupt vector, instead of the `int` instruction directly. The pushf/far call would simulate the `int`.